# App not installed error on Huawei Mate 9

Tags: installation, apk, huawei, 8.0-oreo

I downloaded apk files from Chrome. After the downloads completed, I pressed `Install`. But after 2~3 seconds, it just said `App not installed`. For example, I downloaded an app called "TutuApp". It won't install and doesn't give any information on why so I can fix it.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

My phone is Huawei Mate 9 with Android version 8.0.0.
I'm new to Android and a complete noob.

Comment: Have you provided permissions like as shown in this link https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/sideload-apps-android-8-0-oreo-now-unknown-sources-is-gone-0184399/

Comment: it worked now... I just factory reset my phone and it worked... even though it didn't work after the last 3 times i reset the phone... ehh... it work... thanks for helping anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There's ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4226132) on Stack Overflow.

For my case, Google Protect was on, so I was unable to install app.